# PHP how to add trailing zeros if int is less then 4 digits

Tags: php, numbers

Good day. I am converting a decimal (10, 2) from my mySql database to an int like below

```
$totalprice = number_format($price, 0, ".", "");
```

The issue I am running into is that if the int has no numbers after the decimal place it will convert to a smaller number. For example, if a price of 35.00 is converted to an int using the logic above, it will be 35 instead of 3500 (35 cents instead of 35 dollars). Is there a way in php to add trailing zeros if needed?

Comment: Why don't you just multiply by 100?

Comment: that will work for two digits, but if it is 352 for example ($35.20) it wont work. I guess I could write some logic, but I was wondering if php had a function to deal with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to take a look at BC Math extension. https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php

```
<?php

echo bcmul(35.00, 100);

?>
```

**Output :** 3500

Answer (score 0):

You can use STR_PAD_RIGHT

example :

```
$number = 35;
$number = str_pad($number, 4, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
```